# composer causes segmentation fault

Tags: laravel, composer-php

how to resolve segmentation error in composer?  this happens after installation

> /c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer: line 18:  1024 Segmentation
>   fault      php "${dir}/composer.phar" $*

Comment: The path indicates that you are on Windows, right? Did you invoke Composer via the  cygwin or git-bash CLI?

Comment: through git-bash cli

Answer (score -1):

I'm used cygwin to invoke composer and I ran into the same segmentation error. Solution: I updated cygwin here - https://www.cygwin.com/install.html. Made sure I installed all the php packages. Especially the ones with phar in the description.